# entity framework lazy loading exclude child navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, properties, navigation, lazy-loading

i have two classes, i want select a shop list and it can lazy load ShopLanguages(list),but shoplanguage load shop, shop load language........this is a loop no limited....
i know i can remove "virtual" in class ShopLanguage "public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }" , but. sometimes i want to select ShopLanguage and need to lazy load shop through "public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }" ,so the "virtual" can not remove.
how can i do: when i select shop,shop load shoplanguage,but the loaded shoplanguage stop to load the shop. just exclude the navigation properity(public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }), when i want select shoplanguage include  the navigation properity(public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; })

```
public class Shop
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UnitNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    ........
    public virtual List<ShopLanguage> ShopLanguages { get; set; } 
}
public class ShopLanguage
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1), Key]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual  Language Language { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
}
```

my english is so limited, thank for your help....

Comment: If you use *lazy* loading, you should not run into problems? What do you mean with "exclude from lazy loading"? Eager loading them?

Comment: @D.R. thanks for your answer. i mean: when i select shop,shop can load shoplanguages,but the loaded shoplanguage stop to load it's property(shop,not include the shop property).